# Just / Only just

Tags: word-usage

Here's the context.

> I've ***only just*** had a looked at it. Hum... To be honest, I was quite disappointed to see that the design of the product was not what I had in mind.

Here, ***only*** modifies ***just*** and the meaning is ***right before***, am I right?

Comment: the sentence is weird!

Comment: @MaulikV No so weird. A little British, a little stuffy, but normal. Jihoon: yes, you got it right. The meaning is "right before".

Comment: The sentence is normal, if you change _looked_ to _look_. Clearly we need a noun (look) there, nor a participle.

Comment: *a looked at it* BrE?  @DanBron

Comment: @MaulikV Oh, I put the *-ed* down as a typo or mistranscription. "*I've only just had a look at it*" (not *looked*) is fine, though. As is "*I've only just looked at it*", for that matter.

Comment: Yeah I guess "looked " was a typo after all. assuming the sentence is " 've only just had a look at it..... " , you are correct in assuming that "only just" does mean "right before". "I just had a look at it" -  I only just took a look, I did not try to analyzed it in any way. "I only just had a look at it" - I took a look very recently or only moments ago.

Answer (score 3):

'I've just had a look at it' means I had a look at it (that is, I finished examining it) very recently. 'I've only just had a look at it' is idiomatic English that you'd use to express that you have looked at it very recently and there has not been time since then to do anything else, and there is an implied suggestion that someone expects you to have done more than look at it.

> "What's wrong with the washing machine?"
>   "I've just had a look at it and the motor is not working."
>
> "Have you fixed the washing machine?"
>   "I've *only* just had a look at it!" (I've looked it it and not had time to do anything else)